# Having trouble with python ,by dividing the answer

Tags: python, python-2.7

It is almost perfect just the calculation is giving the wrong result, this is because its dividing the answer by 100
I have to divide the interest rate by 100. So the r value entered by the user needs to be divided by 100

```
import math

p = int(raw_input("Please enter deposit amount: \n"))
r = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n")/100)
t = int(raw_input("Please insert number of years of the investment: \n"))
interest = raw_input("Do you want a simple or compound interest ? \n")

A = p*(1+r**t) 
B = p*(1+r)^t 

if interest == "simple":
    print (A)
else:
    print(B)
```

Comment: `r = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n")/100)` should be `r = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n"))/100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like ettanany said, the main problem was the line on the interest rate input. Also you had a ^ instead of ** on your line 9. I finally added a bit on the if statement to make sure that you only print the result from the compound interest if the user entered the word "compound". Otherwise anything would lead to that unwanted choice.

```
import math

p = int(input("Please enter deposit amount: \n"))
r = int(input("Please input interest rate: \n"))/100
t = int(input("Please insert number of years of the investment: \n"))
interest = input("Do you want a simple or compound interest ? \n")

A = p*(1+r**t) 
B = p*(1+r)**t 

if interest == "simple":
    print (A)
elif interest == "compound":
    print(B)
else:
    print("Error on the interest type")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you just need to change this line:

```
r = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n")/100)
```

To:

```
r = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n"))/100
```

`raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n")/100` means you're dividing a string by 100 the you cast the result to int. Instead, you need to cast then the user input to `int` and you divide it by 100.

**Note:** In Python 2, `10/100` for example returns `0`, so you many need to divide by `100.0` instead of `100`.

```
>>> 10/100
0
>>> 10/100
0
>>> 10/100.0
0.1
```